# GWT Clickable SafeHTMLCell?

Tags: gwt

I defined a safehtmlcell on my datagrid. The html renders just fine but I need that cell to be clickable which works on a clickabletextcell. Here is my code:

```
SafeHtmlCell itemCell = new SafeHtmlCell();
        Column<MyStoreItems, SafeHtml> itemNameColumn = new Column<MyStoreItems, SafeHtml>(itemCell) {
        @Override
        public SafeHtml getValue(MyStoreItems storeItem) {
            SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<table>");
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<td style='font-size:95%;'>");
            sb.appendEscaped(storeItem.getItemName());
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("</td></tr><tr><td>");
            sb.appendEscaped(storeItem.getPackingUnit() + " " + storeItem.getStoreItemName());
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("</td></tr></table>");

            return sb.toSafeHtml();
        }
    };          
    itemNameColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<MyStoreItems, SafeHtml>() {

        @Override
        public void update(int index, MyStoreItems storeItem, SafeHtml value) {
            selectedStoreItem = storeItem;
            selectedIndex = index;
            showSelectedStoreItems(index, storeItem);

        }
    });
```

Is there any workaround to make the safehtml cell clickable?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a class that extends AbstractCell, then override the `onBrowserEvent()` method.

```
public class MySafeHtmlCell extends AbstractCell<SafeHtml> {

  public MySafeHtmlCell() {
     super(BrowserEvents.CLICK);
  }

  @Override
  public void render(Context context, SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (value != null) {
      sb.append(value);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, SafeHtml value, NativeEvent event,
      ValueUpdater<SafeHtml> valueUpdater) {
    String eventType = event.getType();
    if (BrowserEvents.CLICK.equals(eventType)) {
      // Do something...
    }
  }
}
```

In the above implementation, I made the a copy of SafeHtmlCell implementation and added click events handling. Of course you should consider just extending SafeHtmlCell instead of rewriting it.

Unrelated note: instead of using a safeHtmlBuilder consider using [HtmlTemplates](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/client/SafeHtmlTemplates.html)

```
public interface MyTemplate extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
   @Template("<span class=\"{3}\">{0}: <a href=\"{1}\">{2}</a></span>")
   SafeHtml messageWithLink(SafeHtml message, String url, String linkText,
       String style);
}
```

Comment: Note: you need to also *consume* the event in order for this to work (in the constructor).

Comment: you *must* extend AbstractCell because SafeHtmlCell does not expose the Constructor for `String... consumedEvents`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [`ClickableTextCell`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ClickableTextCell.html). It extends [`AbstractSafeHtmlCell`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractSafeHtmlCell.html) and consumes the click as well as the keydown events.